# How to make compileKotlin dependsOn compileJava in gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

While using kotlin with gradle, `compileKotlin` executes before `compileJava`. I need to execute `compileJava` before `compileKotlin`. I tried `compileKotlin.dependsOn(compileJava)` but it gives the Circular dependency build failure.

[image: Circular dependency build failure]

I also tried

`compileJava.dependsOn = compileJava.taskDependencies.values - compileKotlin`

But, it still executes `compileKotlin` before `compileJava`.

**How can I execute `compileJava` before `compileKotlin`?**

Comment: Why would you do that? If you need to process annotations, then you can instead [use kapt](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html), which processes them in both Java and Kotlin at once. Otherwise, I see no good reason to do that, because the Kotlin compiler can read the Java sources and does not require Java to be compiled at that moment. On contrary, since the Java compiler does not understand Kotlin sources, it's necessary to compile Kotlin classes before Java to be able to call Kotlin from Java.

Comment: @hotkey  I am trying to compile java, scala and kotlin together such that kotlin -> scala -> java. I tried the solution described in discuss.gradle.org/t/kotlin-groovy-and-java-compilation/1490‌​3/… but scala compilation wouldn't pick up java sources.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem in a *spike test* with gradle, Java, Kotlin, Scala and Groovy all together - not a real scenario, I recognize it!, but  noticed that (by default, i.e. without any explicit configuration)

1. compileJava dependsOn compileKotlin
2. compileScala dependsOn compileJava
3. compileGroovy dependsOn compileJava

This limits my choices about the order which I can build my sources in: Java compilation can't happen before Kotlin compilation, as you told, and by converse Groovy and Scala compilation can't happen before Java compilation (which was my initial goal).

**My idea** is that the simplest wat to get the desired result is to split my source code into four different projects, **setting up a multi-module project**: this way I can move the problem from defining task dependencies (which as seen I can't control) to defining module dependencies (which I can control very simple through plan dependency management using something like `compile project(':my-dependend-on-project')` in my *dependant* project's `build.gradle`).

This is a very old question, so I suppose you already found a solution; anyway, I'm interested in your opinion about my conclusions about this topic.

Comment: Yup, I ended up building multi-module project as well to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by defining all source sets explicitly:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs 'src/java', 'gen'
    }
    kotlin {
      srcDir 'src/kotlin'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'res'
    }
  }
  test {
    java {
      srcDir 'test'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'test-data'
    }
  }
}
```